# Laravel 5.5 Multi-Auth not redirecting when authenticated

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.5

I'm creating a multi auth system in laravel where there is two types of users: Admins(created by me) and Users(using the native laravel auth system).

If I login as a User, when I try to access the login page when I'm already logged in, it redirects me back to the dashboard but If I login as an Admin, when I access to the Admin login page again, it let's me login again despite being already logged in as an Admin.

Here is my code for the class RedirectIfAuthenticated:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        switch ($guard)
        {
            case 'admin':
                if(Auth::guard($guard)->check())
                {
                    return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
                }
                break;

            default:
                if(Auth::guard($guard)->check())
                {
                    return redirect('/home');
                }
                break;
        }

        /*
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check())
        {
            return redirect('/home');
        }
        */

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Can someone explain me what is happening?

Comment: can u show ur Adminmiddleware's handle function?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the routes you've registered that are meant to be protected for admins? By default when you use the auth middleware it's going to use the default auth guard - not your admin one.

When you register routes you want to protect with the admin guard you will need to do it slightly differently. Either by using a route group or the `middleware` method in a controller.

```
// Cover a block of routes...

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:admin'], function () {
    //
});

// Or do it in your controller...

class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    }
}
```

Comment: I decided to try Hesto MultiAuth. Thanks for the help!